# How do I find which code completion feature is running in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, code-completion, resharper-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017 15.6, with ReSharper 2017.3. They're mostly both ace, but some of their code completion features do the wrong thing more often than they do the right thing. I want to turn them off.

I've managed to turn some off, but can't find which setting is causing some others to run.

Is there some way to find out which specific settings are causing code completion to run? Perhaps some Visual Studio debug log of code completion steps?